# Laravel check if collection is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got this in my Laravel webapp:

```
@foreach($mentors as $mentor)
    @foreach($mentor->intern as $intern)
        <tr class="table-row-link" data-href="/werknemer/{!! $intern->employee->EmployeeId !!}">
            <td>{{ $intern->employee->FirstName }}</td>
            <td>{{  $intern->employee->LastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

How could I check if there are any `$mentors->intern->employee` ?

When I do :

```
@if(count($mentors))
```

It does not check for that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can always count the collection. For example `$mentor->intern->count()` will return how many intern does a mentor have.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-count

In your code you can do something like this

```
foreach($mentors as $mentor)
    @if($mentor->intern->count() > 0)
    @foreach($mentor->intern as $intern)
        <tr class="table-row-link" data-href="/werknemer/{!! $intern->employee->EmployeeId !!}">
            <td>{{ $intern->employee->FirstName }}</td>
            <td>{{  $intern->employee->LastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    @else
        Mentor don't have any intern
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 288):

To determine if there are any results you can do any of the following:

```
if ($mentor->first()) { } 
if (!$mentor->isEmpty()) { }
if ($mentor->count()) { }
if (count($mentor)) { }
if ($mentor->isNotEmpty()) { }
```

**Notes / References**

`->first()`

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_first

`isEmpty()` https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty

`->count()`

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count

`count($mentors)` works because the Collection implements Countable and an internal count() method:

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count

`isNotEmpty()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isnotempty

So what you can do is :

```
if (!$mentors->intern->employee->isEmpty()) { }
```

Comment: yes I know that but a mentor does not always has a intern. So how could I check for that?

Comment: `if ($mentors->has('intern')){}

Answer (score 36):

Starting from **Laravel 5.3** you can simply use :

```
if ($mentor->isNotEmpty()) {
//do something.
}
```

Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-isnotempty

Comment: worked in Lumen as well.

Answer (score 21):

This is the fastest way:

```
if ($coll->isEmpty()) {...}
```

Other solutions like `count` do a bit more than you need which costs slightly more time.

Plus, the `isEmpty()` name quite precisely describes what you want to check there so your code will be more readable.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best solution I found so far.

in blade

```
@if($mentors->count() == 0)
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
        Nothing Found
    </td>
@endif
```

in controller

```
if ($mentors->count() == 0) {
    return "Nothing Found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can convert your collection to an array. Next run an empty method like this:

```
if(empty($collect->toArray())){}
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer

`(!$mentor)`

Is more effective and accurate

Comment: Why would it be more effective and more accurate?

Comment: on the collection this is not working to check if the collection is empty or not