# how i avoid this error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i have this index function to show just my hotels :

```
public function index()
{
        $myhotels = hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id',$myhotels->id)->get();
        return view('moderateur/reservation',compact('reservations'));
}
```

but when there is no hotel i got this error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

itry this but still the same

```
public function index()
{
    $myhotels = hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if (!hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->exists()){
        $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id',$myhotels->id)->get();
        return view('moderateur/reservation',compact('reservations'));
    }
    return view('moderateur/reservation');
}
```

how can i fix this :( ? and when there is no hotels i want to be shown 'no hotels'

Comment: Have you tried firstOrFail() and control the exception? Using try/catch

Comment: yes bu i got just error 404 i want the same view but with a message

Comment: Catch the error and return your own custom message to the view. What message do you want to return anyway?

Comment: ' You Have no data  ' but not in the 404error page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel check if collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839303/laravel-check-if-collection-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the object is empty before executing the rest of your code or you firstOrFail().

eg.

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    if (!empty($myhotels) {
      ...    
      return view('moderateur/reservation');
    }
}
```

Comment: i got Undefined variable: reservations cause i have to show reservations on view

Comment: Yes but in this case you have no reservations because $myhotels is empty. So if your blade view wrap it in a conditional statement and check if $reservations is empty. If it is display your error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the hotel exists:

```php
public function index()
{
    $myhotels = hotel::where('created_by', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if ($myhotels) {
        $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id', $myhotels->id)->get();
        return view('moderateur/reservation', compact('reservations'));
    }
    return view('moderateur/reservation');
}
```

While you first tried to fetch the hotel, then you were checking if the hotel doesn't exist. Since it doesn't exist, you were entering the if statement.

And then in the view:

```
@if ($reservations)
   show reservation details
@else
   show that the reservaiton is not found
@endif
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements

Comment: i got this error Undefined variable: reservations (View: C:\Users\yass\Desktop\E-tourisme-44\E-tourisme-5554\resources\views\moderateur\reservation.blade.php)

Comment: Ok, then in the vew, you need to check if the variable $reservations exists. If not, then show empty message. I'll update my answer.

Comment: still the same probleme

Comment: How do you check your variable in the view? Update your question with that info please.

Comment: Replace `$reservation` with `$reservations`

Comment: yes i do i make another qst https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225494/how-can-i-check-there-is-an-variable-laravel

Comment: Ok, then try with `isset($reservations)`