# how can i check there is an variable laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i have this on my view  im trying to pass `$reservations` when there is some reservations in DB there is no error but when it is empty i got error

> Undefined variable: reservations (View: C:\Users\yass\Desktop\E-tourisme-44\E-tourisme-5554\resources\views\moderateur\reservation.blade.php)

Template

```
<tbody>
                        @if($reservations )

                        @foreach($reservations as $reservation)

                            <tr>      
                                <td> {{$reservation->children}} </td>
                                <td> {{$reservation->checkin}} </td>
                                <td> {{$reservation->checkout}} </td>
                                <td>

                        @endforeach
                       @else
                                    <div>
                                       No Data
                                    </div>
                            @endif

                        </tbody>
```

and this is my function

```
public function index()
{
    $myhotels = hotel::where('created_by', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if ($myhotels) {
        $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id', $myhotels->id)->get();
        return view('moderateur/reservation', compact('reservations'));
    }
    return view('moderateur/reservation');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel check if collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839303/laravel-check-if-collection-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```php
@if(isset($reservations))
```

Answer (score 3):

To make your code work, instead

```
@if($reservations )
```

use

```
@if(! empty($reservations))
```

Also instead combining `@if` with `@foreach` for displaying "no data" consider using `@forelse @empty` instead. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops

Comment: Will still fail when there's no `$reservation`

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski  why? No, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@isset($reservations)
  //your code
@endisset
```

Or you can write your code like this

```
{{ $reservations ?? null }}
```