# How to not show empty collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have tried adding this code to my Blade:

```
@if(!empty($user_wallet))
    <li class="mt-3" id="theWallet">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pay_wallet" value="1" id="thisWrapper">
            <label class="form-check-label small mr-3" for="thisWrapper">
            Pay with Wallet
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
@endif
```

So this means, if user has not any Wallet, do not show the div with id of `theWallet`.

But now the problem is, it still shows the div and checkbox however the user does not have any Wallet stored at the DB.

And when I `dd($user_wallet)`, I get this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2562 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Meaning that, it's empty. But why it still shows the div?

Comment: try with `if(!$user_wallet->isEmpty())` collection method

Comment: `empty(): Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals false. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.` and you have a array, even when the array is empty, the variable itself is not,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel check if collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839303/laravel-check-if-collection-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello if $user_wallet contains the collection data then you need to change the `@if` condition.

Replace your

```
@if(!empty($user_wallet))
```

To

```
@if(!$user_wallet->isEmpty()) OR @if($user_wallet->isNotEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isset()` function with `empty()` function.

Replace your if condition with

```
@if(!empty($user_wallet))
```

to

```
@if(!empty($user_wallet) && isset($user_wallet)) 

or 

@if(isset($user_wallet))
```

The `isset()` function is an inbuilt function in PHP which checks whether a variable is set and is not NULL.

This function also checks if a declared variable, array or array key has null value, if it does, `isset()` returns false, it returns true in all other possible cases.

Comment: It's a collection instance. It always is set as being passed to view. The thing that needs to check here is, the emptiness of collection.

Comment: Required reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403