# How to check collection empty or not in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is my controller:

```
public function reportDetail(Request $request)
   {
       $p_report = Report::office()->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subdays(60))->first(['column_thirteen', 'column_fourteen']);
       return view('acland.report.report_detail', $data);
   }
```

This is my view code:

```
@if ($p_report->column_thirteen !== Null)
<td style="border: 1px solid black" class="input_bangla" id="column_one">{{ $p_report->column_thirteen}}
<input type="hidden" name="column_one" value="{{$p_report->column_thirteen}}"></td>
@else
<td style="border: 1px solid black" class="input_bangla"><input type="text" name="column_one" id="column_one" class="form-control" style="min-width: 100px"></td>
@endif
```

When I try this I got:

> Trying to get property 'column_thirteen' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\report-management\resources\views\acland\report\type\rent_certificate.blade.php)

How can I check if data empty or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel check if collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839303/laravel-check-if-collection-is-empty)

Comment: you don't have a Collection ... `first` returns a single model or `null`, not a Collection

Answer (score 2):

### There's some methods you can try:

add an `!empty()` check:

```
@if (!empty($p_report))
   // code if not empty
@else
   // code if empty
@endif
```

Or add an `isset()` check:

```
@if (isset($p_report))
   // code if not empty
@else
   // code if empty
@endif
```

Do a count:

```
@if ($p_report->count() != 0)
   // code if not empty
@else
   // code if empty
@endif
```

Comment: they don't have a collection, they have a `null` so calling the `count` method on it would be the same error

Answer (score 2):

```
$p_report = Report::office()->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subdays(60))
->first(['column_thirteen', 'column_fourteen']);// return model or null
```

you can check it same as :

```
if (!$p_report) {
   // Do stuff if it doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using ->first() in your eloquent then you can check empty or not with is_object() and !is_object(), and when using ->get() you can check it with isEmpty() or isNotEmpty()

for example:
when using ->first() then

```
if(is_object($p_report)) {
// some code
}
```

And when using ->get() then

```
if($p_report->isNotEmpty()){
// some code
}
```